# Spark Job stop when Cassandra is busy or unreachable

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, cassandra-2.0

I'm running a Spark Streaming job with Spark version 1.4.1, Cassandra and Kafka.

The Job read events from a Kafka topic elaborate it and store to Cassandra table.

Sometimes the job stops and from the logs I see the following exception.

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 13.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 16, localhost): java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {cassandraHost}:9042
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:164)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:150)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:150)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.createNewValueAndKeys(RefCountedCache.scala:31)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.acquire(RefCountedCache.scala:56)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.openSession(CassandraConnector.scala:81)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:109)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.write(TableWriter.scala:139)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.streaming.DStreamFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DStreamFunctions.scala:33)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.streaming.DStreamFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DStreamFunctions.scala:33)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [cassandraHost/cassandraHostIp:9042] Channel has been closed))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:223)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:78)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1272)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.getMetadata(Cluster.java:336)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:157)
    ... 15 more
```

I realized that this happens when Cassandra is busy or unreachable.

Is There a way to retry connection without the job stops?

My application is written with Java 1.8